# jQuery image roundabout only to link front image

Tags: jquery, image

I have been working on an image roundabout plugin provided in the following link http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/ and all is working fine apart from the fact that whichever link I click on; be it the front or the back, the roundabout does slide round to the front, but then takes you to the link for the image that you have just clicked... therefore rendering the roundabout pretty much useless.

I have only just start learning jQuery not too long ago and am quite inexperienced and feel I may be missing something simple here. I only want the image at the front of the roundabout to link to its necessary page. When i click on any other images behind the front one, I only want the roundabout to swing that image to the front, but then enable the link on click when that image is at the front

Below is what I have so far

**HTML**

```
<section id="carousel">
<ol class="next">
    <li><a href="http://bandonthewall.org/"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-1.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-2.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://bandonthewall.org/"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-3.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-4.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://bandonthewall.org/"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-5.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-6.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://bandonthewall.org/"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-7.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-8.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://bandonthewall.org/"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-9.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-10.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://bandonthewall.org/"><img src="assets/images/carousel-item-11.png"></a></li>
</ol>
</section>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('ol').roundabout({
         btnNext: ".next",
        enableDrag: true,
      });

   $('a').click(function(e){
        link = $(this).attr("href");
        location.href=link;
    });  });
```

I would really appreciate help with this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this block:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    link = $(this).attr("href");
    location.href=link;
});
```

Try this:

```
$('.roundabout-moveable-item a').click(function(e){
    if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('roundabout-in-focus')) {
        link = $(this).attr("href");
        location.href=link;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

What I have done is test if the `a`'s parent `li` element is the current one that is in front (this is specified by the plugin's class `.roundabout-in-focus`). If it is, then allow the link to go through. If not (if it is any of the ones behind), then prevent the link from activating.

Let me know if this works. I'm not very familiar with the plugin, this is based on quick research. If it does work, here's a slimmer alternative version of the block above:

```
$('.roundabout-moveable-item a').click(function(e){
    if(!$(this).parent('li').hasClass('roundabout-in-focus')) {
        e.preventDefault();
});
```